# Which SQL statement has a better performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, I am a fairly inexperienced SQL developer and I was wondering which of these statements is faster.

It's just about an "*m-to-n*" relationship between a `store` and a `store_admin` using a `store_admin_store` table for the relations. In those SQL statements I want to get all `store`s that a `store_admin` is "*assigned*" to. There are **no** additional indices. Only the IDs and corresponding foreign keys are indexed.

Is it this one:

```
--
-- STATEMENT 1
--
SELECT
  store.name
FROM
  (SELECT 
     store_admin_store.store_id 
   FROM 
     store_admin_store
   WHERE
     store_admin_store.store_admin_id = 1) as stores, store
WHERE
  stores.store_id = store.id
```

or that one:

```
--
-- STATEMENT 2
--
SELECT
  store.name
FROM store
  JOIN store_admin_store ON store_admin_store.store_admin_id = 1
WHERE store.id = store_admin_store.store_id
```

or is there no difference at all?

The reason why I'm asking is because if I leave out the `WHERE` clause of the second statement:

```
--
-- STATEMENT 2 (without WHERE clause)
--
SELECT
  store.name
FROM store
  JOIN store_admin_store ON store_admin_store.store_admin_id = 1
```

I can see that the `store.id` gets crossed with `store_admin_store.store_id` resulting in a very large table and I am not sure what happens exactly in each of the statements.

Or is there even a faster way to do this?

Comment: What did the execution plans say? What are your indexes?

Comment: (1) The one that runs fastest has the better performance (you can try out both).  (2) Never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join`.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @VincentSavard Sorry, what is an execution plan? If you mean just the time that the query took I am not sure how to see that (I am using phpPgAdmin here) but I will take a look at it. The indexes are just the `id` columns of the tables and respectively the foreign keys - no extra indices are used here.

Comment: It really depends on many factors....... rule of thumb - you can use a JOIN as its  faster than subquery in many cases,

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay, so my first statement violates that rule already :D

Comment: @Microtechie By subquery you mean the nestex `(SELECT .. ) AS stores` I guess? But what about the second query without the `WHERE` clause? Isn't that "intermediary" table generated and then filtered?

Comment: Also try out runtime for `select store.name from store s where exists (select 1 from store_admin_store where store_admin_id = 1 and store_id = s.id)`. I am just curious how this query performs with your dataset against other queries

Comment: @StefanFalk Please read about implicit vs explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server Management Studio you can gather some statistics about your queries to determine which is faster.

These options can be found under:

- Query -> "Include Actual Execution Plan"
- Query -> "Include Client Statistics"

Using the Client Statistics you can run multiple trials and see the total execution time and the breakdown of the query (units are milliseconds). I have a couple of tables that I ran your queries on (obviously modified to grab data from my tables). I also matched the IDs instead of simply searching for where an ID was 1. These two tables contain about 2 million records together and the total execution time is as follows:

**Statement 1:** *192.00 ms*

**Statement 2:** *193.60 ms*

Modifying Statement 1 to have a join instead of the comma.

**Modified Statement 1:** *189.60 ms*

As you can see, the time does not change very much on a grab from two tables with a couple million records. If your database is smaller than I really wouldn't worry about which one is "faster" as it is probably more of a waste of time than anything. Query execution time will vary by a few milliseconds anyways.

Hopefully this is helpful and it wouldn't be surprising to get slightly different results but I would say it is almost always faster using joins and only select the data you need from tables and cast them to be used in the join. This will eliminate any un-needed data from being gathered and saved. If my understanding is wrong I am sure someone will say so in the comments! :^)

**Example:**

```
select table1.ID from (select ID from tableA) as table1 join (select ID from tableB) as table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Comment: The query is tagged `postgresql` not `sql-server`

Comment: Whoops! Thanks... I would think the numbers should still be similar but I guess my answer doesn't directly apply...